# Get value of super attribute of configurable products in magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, price, product-attribute, associate-products

I tried to get value of attributes of configurable products.

[image]

my question is: how to get the price and selected value of associated product?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();// Or you can load your product here
$_attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
print_r($_attributes);
```